# How do I prevent jump to section when clicking on an anchor tag, without blocking its other innate behaviors?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, slider, carousel, anchor

So, I've made a slider with HTML/CSS. I've used links () to use as buttons to move from one slide to another (kind of like [this slider](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Xkj54BqNqiQ/YANBQFkHQ6I/AAAAAAAADKQ/zJi1zwdsF-YmwGBpHzmfaKqwhYFk8fSOQCLcBGAsYHQ/s0/thumbnailnew%2B2020-10-30.png), though I didn't use this tutorial. So it's like each slide has its own button, rather than having only two buttons for the previous and next slide).

But, my slider navigation is above my slider. So everytime I click on one of the buttons, it jumps to the slide and I have to scroll back up to see my navigation. I know the problem is the innate behavior of the anchor tag that causes that jump. However, I can't use `preventDefault()` or `onclick="return false"` because it blocks all other innate behaviors of my  links - and I still need them. I just want that automatic scroll to not happen. Is there a way?

Code for those interested:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-nav">
                <a class="btn-slider-nav" href="#services-container-1" ></a>
                <a class="btn-slider-nav" href="#services-container-2"></a>
                <a class="btn-slider-nav" href="#services-container-3" ></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slider">
                <div id="services-container-1" class="services-container">
                    <div class="services-title">
                        <p>Blah Blah Blah 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="services-text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur convallis pretium nulla id maximus. Donec
                            vel lacinia
                            nisi. Nullam sollicitudin turpis non justo vehicula, ac rhoncus est hendrerit. Nunc et dapibus arcu.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="services-container-2" class="services-container">
                    <div class="services-title">
                        <p>Blah Blah Blah 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="services-text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur convallis pretium nulla id maximus. Donec
                            vel lacinia
                            nisi. Nullam sollicitudin turpis non justo vehicula, ac rhoncus est hendrerit. Nunc et dapibus arcu.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="services-container-3" class="services-container">
                    <div class="services-title">
                        <p>Blah Blah Blah 3</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="services-text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur convallis pretium nulla id maximus. Donec
                            vel lacinia
                            nisi. Nullam sollicitudin turpis non justo vehicula, ac rhoncus est hendrerit. Nunc et dapibus arcu.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
.slider-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
    display: flex;
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    overflow-x: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.slider .services-container {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.slider-nav {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 15%;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.slider-nav a {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    transition: opacity ease 250ms;
    z-index: 1;
    outline: 1px dashed black;
    outline-offset: 4rem;
}
```

I've tried `preventDefault` and `onclick="return false"` but it blocks all other innate behaviors of my  links. I've also tried to write a custom javascript function initiated when I click on one of the links, that would store the X and Y offset in variables and "take" the position of these offsets back to these values but it doesn't seem to work either.